# Understanding the phonon

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, crystals, phonons

It is said that the phonon is the equivalent of the photon in Solid state physics.
I cannot see how,when i try to give an interpretation to the phonon.

What i am trying to say is the following:

If we have a source of an EM wave (bright light for example) we can consider the light as made of particles, with a certain energy (E= h*$\nu$).A light beam that is being absorbed by a surface, it transmits a certain energy to this surface/medium.We can interpret this process as if the atoms on the surface absorb the "countless" photons.

Now how can i understand the phonon? It is hard to put into words. If we have a 3d lattice where does a phonon begin and where does it end? The photon can be idealized like a quasi-particle with no mass that travels with light speed in a medium. So how can we confine a phonon? Like is the oscillation of a single atom in the lattice enough to be called a phonon, or do we need more atoms moving as a group with the same frequency,maybe with a phase difference to call that a phonon? Can some of the atoms in the lattice represent a phonon with a certain frequency and energy and some other one with another frequency and energy?

What would 1 phonon look like?

Comment: What does “SSF” stand for?

Comment: The phonon is similar to a photon in the sense that it's a quantum of the lattice waves/oscillations. (Like photon is a quantum of the elecromagnetic waves.) One phonon is not the oscillation of an individual (or a group of atoms), but the oscillation of the whole lattice. I think when we talk about phonons, it usually/often means different standing wave states in the lattice, although not necessarily I suppose.

Comment: @G.Smith I think solid state physics, as in mani languages physics is with "f", probabli a spelling mistake.

Comment: This site operates in English, so that would be SSP (and still be sufficiently unclear to warrant spelling out)..

Comment: G.Smith Solid State Physics